# Store user input as wildcard

Tags: matlab, wildcard, file-processing

I am having some trouble with a data processing function in MATLAB. The function takes the name of the file to be processed as an input, finds the desired files, and reads in the data.

However, several of the desired files are variants, such as Data_00.dat, Data.dat, or Data_1_March.dat. Within my function, I would like to search for all files containing Data and condense them into one usable file for processing.

To solve this, I would like desiredfile to be converted into a wildcard.

Here is the statement I would like to use.

```
selectedfiles = dir *desiredfile*.dat   % Search for file names containing desiredfile
```

This returns all files containing the variable name desiredfile, rather than the user input.

The only solution that I can think of is writing a separate function that manually condenses all the variants into one file before my function is run, but I am trying to keep the number of files used down and would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate strings for that. Considering `desiredFile` as a variable.

```
desiredFile = input('Files: ');
selectedfiles = dir(['*' desiredfile '*.dat'])   % Search for file names containing desiredfile
```

Enclosing strings between square brackets `[string1 string2 ... stringN]`concatenates them. Matlab's [dir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function receives a string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve that using the `dir` command.

```
dataSets = dir('/path/to/dir/containing/Data*.dat');
dataSets = {dataSets.name};
```

Now simply loop over them, more information [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).

To quote the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) help:

> dir lists the files and folders in the MATLAB® current folder. Results appear in the order returned by the operating system.
>
> dir name lists the files and folders that match the string name. When name is a folder, dir lists the contents of the folder. Specify name using absolute or relative path names. You can use wildcards (*).